# Angular 6 and Angular materials printing a div returning empty fields with no data and no css attached

Tags: angular, printing, angular-material, angular6

I am having a difficulty in printing div content.

The div is based on angular 6 and its related angular material version.

The div has the following script:

```
 <div class="order-info-container" id="divToPrint">
    <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Name" [value]="info.name" readonly>
    </mat-form-field>                        

    <mat-form-field>
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Address" matTextareaAutosize [value]="info.address" readonly></textarea>
    </mat-form-field>
 </div>
```

And the button is:

```
<button mat-raised-button type="button" *ngIf="lat!=0 && lng!=0" (click)="print();">Print Order</button>
```

The typescript function of print() is:

```
print(){
    let divToPrint = document.getElementById('divToPrint').innerHTML;
    let newWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'top=0,left=0,height=100%,width=auto');
    newWindow.document.open();
    newWindow.document.write(`
    <html>
        <head>
          <title>Print tab</title>
          <style>

          </style>
        </head>
        <body onload="window.print();window.close()">${divToPrint}   
        </body>
      </html>
    `);
    newWindow.document.close();
  }
```

And result was empty text boxes with no data, and no css attached.

I think, angular is not displaying the 2 variables as they have been imported from database. But they actually exist on the screen.

[Here is an image of what a printed page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXzUx.jpg). Empty fields and no attached angular material css into it.